# What's the purpose and function of int.class

Tags: java

I accidentally found that this works:

```
Class<?> a;

a = int.class;
System.out.println(a); // int

a = Integer.class;      
System.out.println(a); // class java.lang.Integer
```

What does it really mean / do for primitives?

I tried and neither `List<int>` nor `List<int.class>` works (yeah, I know I have to use Integer). Also, obviously, I can't invoke `getClass()` on primitives, so it's useless for type checking of any sort.

In what situation would I use `int.class` and why is it even present in the language?

Comment: Oh my, `void.class`! In the spec, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use it when you are trying to locate a method having an int argument via the reflection API.

Answer (score 1):

From the specs:

```
The type of p.class, where p is the name of a primitive type 
(§4.2), is Class<B>, where B is the type of an expression of 
type p after boxing conversion (§5.1.7).
```

And

```
A class literal evaluates to the Class object for the named 
type (or for void) as defined by the defining class loader 
(§12.2) of the class of the current instance.
```

So how about

```
Class<Integer> a = int.class;
```

When to use: Lots of reflection use cases (for instance in argparse4j they use it to map from command line parameters to methods).